# Real Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, real-algebraic-geometry

I am reading the proof of the Real Nullstellensatz (from the Real Algebraic Geometry book, by Bochnak, Coste and Roy). I add a picture of this proof

[image]

And there is a notation I had not seen before: the *ring of fractions $B_{\overline{P}}$*. I would appreciate any help to understand this. Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to understand about it? Have you looked here? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RingofFractions.html

Comment: Thank you. I think what I am looking for is for the -localization at `P` -. I will check that. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear this from the unanswered queue, this is the localization of $B$ at the element $\overline{P}$.

The [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)) of a (commutative) ring at a multiplicatively closed subset $S$ is the set of pairs $(r,s)$ with addition defined by $(r,s)+(r',s')=(rs'+r's,ss')$, multiplication defined by $(r,s)\cdot(r',s')=(rr',ss')$, and two pairs $(r,s)$ and $(r',s')$ are equal iff there exists some $t\in S$ so that $t(rs'-r's)=0$.

This specific example is the case when $S=\{1,\overline{P},\overline{P}^2,\overline{P}^3,\cdots\}$ and $R=B$. In the language of geometry, this corresponds to considering the open subset/subvariety/subscheme which is the complement of the vanishing locus of $\overline{P}$.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have a clear idea to continue reading the proof.

Comment: @AlejandroDz You're welcome. If this answers your question, please click the checkmark over by the votes. If it doesn't, please leave a comment describing where you need further clarification.